# Creating canvas connected app in Salesforce

Tags: visualforce, canvas

I'm trying to create my very first canvas connected app in salesforce and I need help how to call that in visualforce page and I have setup creating connected app and also i have external app sample here in the [github](https://github.com/short000/salesforce-canvas-dotnet), my question is how to call the external app from visualforce page?

followed [this blog](https://saramorgan.net/2014/12/04/force-com-canvas-and-net-considerations/) and end-up in github

Comment: Can you post any code to demonstrate what you have tried in Salesforce?

Comment: here is the detail step by step what i have done so far: https://github.com/short000/salesforce-canvas-dotnet/blob/master/SalesForceOAuthExamples/ReadMe.pdf

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You will use [apex:canvasApp](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.platform_connect.meta/platform_connect/canvas_app_vf_component_ref.htm) tag on your visualforce markup

```
<apex:page controller="JSONGeneratorSample">
    <apex:canvasApp developerName="mycanvas" parameters="{!generateJSON}" />
</apex:page>
```

Note that you can either use Application Name or Developer Name .

Once your Visualforce page is rendered ,it will make a GET Request to the Canvas URL that you have in your connected application .

Unless you validate the Signed request sent ,Your page will display signed request failed .

The consumer Secret is the private key that can be used to validate the signed request .

Once the Signed request is validated ,you will get the Canvas Request Object .

[image]

The canvas Request Object will have the Parameters you have sent in parameters attribute in your visualforce page .

Also Canvas Request Object will have userinfo of salesforce and other details and Environment Variables .The sample Canvas Request will look like [this](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.platform_connect.meta/platform_connect/canvas_request_object.htm)

Once you have Environment variables and Signed Request token your page thats rendered from external server can make REST API calls to SFDC .

The [Canvas Documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.platform_connect.meta/platform_connect/canvas_app_vf_component_ref.htm) provides examples of how you can execute these .

Comment: in the apex: tag you `parameters="{!generateJSON}"` what exactly are sending in as a parameters?

Comment: @NickKahn It will be your custom parameters .Its a key and value combination the external system